# Escape commands / ByteArray to Readable Text C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ascii, escpos

I have developed a POS application using C#, for receipt printing, I'm using PrinterUtility library from NuGet, it converts a string to ByteArray, saves it and sends it to a receipt printer to print it. since I don't have a receipt printer, how can I convert the generated file to a readable text? I opened the result file using notepad++ and content is shown in the picture attached

[click on the link to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBcco.png)

I wonder if this ByteArray result can be rendered as text and shown in a RichTextBox or if there is any way to create a virtual receipt printer that can display the result?

Your help will be appreciated.

Link to the File
[Click Here To Download The File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ACvlB07bTrjVf7XGCconAWGJ80MFg_V5)

Comment: if you can provide file, I can give a try.

Comment: @Prakash, Here is the file  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ACvlB07bTrjVf7XGCconAWGJ80MFg_V5

Comment: Hi friend, these are called control character.  A control character or non-printing character is a code point (a number) in a character set, that does not represent a written symbol. you can find the details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes)

each character has it's own meaning 
1.  `SOH` is Start Of Header
2.  `STX` is Start of text
and so on

please let me know if it helps you to understand

Comment: @Prakash, yes it does help to understand the characters, but anyway or any simulator can preview the results?

Comment: Not a complete set, not C#, but this tool may be useful. [receipt-print-hq/escpos-tools](https://github.com/receipt-print-hq/escpos-tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple parser.
It detects `SOH` (Start of Heading) and `GS` (Group Separator) escape codes and ignores/skips `NUL` and `ESC` code and their connected identifier, if any.
The parsing terminates when all bytes are read or a `ETX` (End of Text) code is found.

It's a pretty simple nested while loop, so you can easily adapt it, to handle *special cases*.

The parsed chars are added to a StringBuilder object.

► Note that this handles only ASCII chars. For languages that don't use ASCII chars, you need to build an array of bytes (not an array of chars with a StringBuilder), then use `Encoding.[Some Encoding].GetString([Parsed Byte Array])` to decode the array of bytes to a .Net string format.

Use a monospaced Font (Consolas, Courier New etc.) in your RichTextBox.

```
var bytes = [Your Byte Array];
var charBuffer = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length);

int nul = 0x00;   // NULL char
int soh = 0x01;   // Start of Heading
int etx = 0x03;   // End of Text
int esc = 0x1B;   // Escape
int gs  = 0x1D;   // Group Separator

int pos = 0;
while (pos < bytes.Length) {
    byte byteValue = bytes[pos];
    if (byteValue == soh || byteValue == gs || byteValue == nul) {
        pos += byteValue == gs ? 3 : 1;
        if (pos == etx) break;

        while (bytes[pos] != gs && bytes[pos] != esc) {
            charBuffer.Append((char)bytes[pos]);
            pos += 1;
        }
    }
    pos += 1;
}
richTextBox1.Text = charBuffer.ToString();
```